# Cannot select Sheet in ActiveWorkbook inside XLAM Excel-AddIn

Tags: vba

I am trying to select a worksheet inside my ActiveWorkbook (the one that calls the macro). It appears to select the sheet but it hasn't when I try and print out the ActiveSheet name.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query Tables").Activate ' Select has the same result as Activate
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query Tables").Name
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Name
```

This is how I call my Sub inside the Add-In from the workbook.

```
Application.Run "QTAnalyser.xlam!MyMacro()"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer, it's the brackets!!!

"Application.Run "QTAnalyser.xlam!MyMacro()" runs the macro twice, as well as not selecting the sheet

This fixes it:

Application.Run "QTAnalyser.xlam!MyMacro"

I'm not sure why it has this effect, but you shouldn't use brackets even if you have an argument apparently

Answer (score 0):

<s>The Workbook and Worsheet objects of a .xlam file may be in-activated, because they're not supposed to be accessible to Excel User Interface.</s>

Modify your code like this:

```
Call Application.Workbooks("MyAddIn.xlam").Activate
Call ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query Tables").Activate
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query Tables").Name
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Name
```

where "MyAddIn.xlam" should be changed to your file name.

**Later Edit**

The `ActiveASheet` property may be linked to the `Application`, to a `Window` or to a `Workbook` object. To solve this ambiguity, try:

```
Call Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query Tables").Activate
MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query Tables").Name
MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbTab & Application.ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: The sheets in question are not in the add-in, they are in the active workbook.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Sorry, I combined the title "Cannot select Sheet in ActiveWorkbook inside XLAM Excel-AddIn" with the info in the text " select a worksheet inside my ActiveWorkbook (the one the contains the macro)" and I concluded that you want to select inside the .xlam.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I call the sub from inside the macro then it moves to the sheet I want. But if I call it from outside then it doesn't. I have edited the problem to show how I call it.